# Unmount wrapper automatically

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vitest

I am using Vitest along with Testing Library - Vue for unit testing my frontend code. I have been following this pattern:

```
describe("LoadingSpinner", () => {
  const defaultWidth = "4rem";
  const defaultHeight = "4rem";

  it("should have a default height of 4rem when no props are passed", async () => {
    const wrapper = render(LoadingSpinner);

    const component = await screen.findByRole("status");

    expect(component.style.height).toBe(defaultHeight);

    wrapper.unmount();
  });

  //etc...
}
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to automatically unmount the wrapper, rather than manually calling *wrapper.unmount()*? If I don't unmount the wrapper, each test creates a new LoadingSpinner and thus *screen.findByRole()* fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, there is an enableAutoUnmount in vue test utils

```js
describe("LoadingSpinner", () => {
  enableAutoUnmount(afterEach); // <----- add this
  const defaultWidth = "4rem";
```